# Add spring macro as parameter to Freemarker macro

Tags: freemarker

I have the code snippet below, and want to give the output from <@spring.message "name"/> as paraneter to the macro (the placeholder parameter).

Providing it directly as I tried doing below didnt't work, anyone knows how I should do it?

```
<td class="rightCell"><b><@spring.message "name"/>:</b></td>
<td class="leftCell"><@createUserInputItemModifiedv2 "name", "name", "text", @spring.message "name" /></td>

<#macro createUserInputItemModifiedv2 attributeName, errorMessageName, inputType, placeholder>
   <input class="edit" type="${inputType}" id="${attributeName}" name="${attributeName}" placeholder="${placeholder}" value="${user[attributeName]!}"/><br/>
   <#if validationErrors?? && validationErrors[attributeName]??>
      <div class="errorMessage" id="${errorMessageName}Error">
         ${validationErrors[attributeName]!}
      </div>
    </#if>
</#macro>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `spring.message` should also be a FreeMarker function, not just a FreeMarker macro. Macros has no return value (they might directly print to the output writer as a side-effect) so you can't call them where an expression is expected. Anyway... how to work this around right now. Looking at the source code of Spring, *maybe* this will work:

```
<#function message code><#return springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(code)></#function>
```

You could create a `utils.ftl` or something, (auto-)`#import` it as `u`, and then you can do `<@createUserInputItemModifiedv2 ..., u.message("name")>` in your templates. (Actually, it could be made more convenient, so that you can just write `msg.name` or like, but let's not go into that here.)

However, I'm not sure if there's any backward compatibility guarantee regarding `springMacroRequestContext` or its content. So ultimately this should be fixed in Spring.